# Styling a custom element in Polymer

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0

I am working on a Polymer project, and am struggling because the code was written for `Polymer 0.5`. As I am inspecting the element, I see something like this:

```
<custom-elem layout vertical center center-justified style="width: 25%;">
  <h1>Yay! </h1>
  <p>
    awesome!
  </p>
</custom-elem>
```

When I mess around with removing the `"layout, vertical, center, center-justified"` in the *element inspector*, it changes the layout in the legacy (Polymer 0.5) code. When I try to implement the same thing in 1.0, no styles are applied and when removed nothing changes.

What are these classes? Are they some sort of legacy code from Polymer 0.5? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/paper-styles

Instead of attributes classes are now used because attributes were slow on some browsers.

Comment: but these attributes are part of some sort of external library, or are they contained within Polymer?

Comment: They are one of the additional packages Polymer provides. There was some controversy about including these styles by default in Polymer 0.5 (about size and conflicts with other CSS frameworks). AFAIR this is why you now need to opt in.

Comment: Ah I see. I saw some other questions and saw that the layout verticals and centers are included within paper-styles. Thanks a lot!